# IntelliJ warning about 'getAt' with int on JSON array

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

Take the following lines of Groovy code:

```
String json = """
        {
           "_embedded":{
              "someArray":[
                 "zero",
                 "one",
                 "two",
                 "three",
                 "four",
                 "five",
                 "six"
              ]
           }
        }
    """
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsed = jsonSlurper.parseText(json)
def value = parsed._embedded.someArray[5]
```

The last line returns the sixth element of the JSON array.
However, IntelliJ complains about it with the following warning:

```
'getAt' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.Integer)'
```

As this is a quite common pattern in our tests, the warnings cause a lot of clutter. What can I do to get rid of just these warnings?

To be explicit: the code works well, it's simple to read and perfectly matches our needs, so I'm looking for a way to change the behavior of IntelliJ, not the structure of our code.

IntelliJ's support for dynamic methods seems to be a good solution, but unfortunately, the hint "Add dynamic method" is not shown if the method exists, but with a different signature. A way to tweak/hack that would be possible solution to our issue.

Comment: What is the actual data structure looking like? Is intellij tripping
over an implicit spread operator?  Otherwise: "intellij vs dynamic
language: zero to seven trillion..."

Comment: I've extended the code fragment. Is it clear now?

Comment: that looks rather normal to me and i'd say, that intellij is throwing a tantrum... again...

Comment: Yes. Actually, it has a mechanism for such issues, but that is not enabled in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Groovy what type you expect like this:

```
String json = """
        {
           "_embedded":{
              "someArray":[
                 "zero",
                 "one",
                 "two",
                 "three",
                 "four",
                 "five",
                 "six"
              ]
           }
        }
    """
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsed = jsonSlurper.parseText(json) as Map<String, Object>
def array = parsed._embedded.someArray as List<String>
def value = array[5]
```

It should solve most warnings, but it's very cumbersome.

A better way is to create Groovy classes representing your domain objects:

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable
import groovy.json.*

@Immutable
class MyJson {
    Embedded _embedded
}

@Immutable
class Embedded {
    List<String> someArray
}
```

The `Immutable` annotation adds proper constructors to the classes, including one taking a `Map` so that the JSON can be passed to it, and if it "validates" (object fields match the class fields and their types), it should work:

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsed = new MyJson(jsonSlurper.parseText(json))
println parsed
println parsed._embedded
def value = parsed._embedded.someArray[5]
println value
```

### Turning off warnings without changing the code

If like to live dangerously, IntelliJ won't bother you as long as you turn off the relevant inspections in Preferences.

See the screenshot below:

[image: IntelliJ Preferences for Groovy inspections]

You can turn off any warnings that you think are not needed by simply un-checking them in the list.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not being explicit immediately. We really like our current code (for our purpose), so I'm looking for ways to influence IntelliJ without changing the code.

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing where you can turn inspections on/off, hope that helps.

Comment: @Bert For the warning you mentioned in the question, you should turn off "Groovy > Assignment issues > Incompatible type assignments"

Comment: Too bad there is no safe way to stop this nonsense warning. I'm going to log a ticket at Jetbrains. Thanks for your help!